# Is there any Memory Align issue on Electric Fence - Cross compiled for MIPS?

Tags: c++, c, linux, mips, electric-fence

I am trying to use Electric Fence on my Embedded box - MIPS based. when I run a simple application - it seems to be good. When I am running on an actual application - a complex application which tries to use everything - right from dbus to sqlite. I get a crash- segmentation fault - a desired one. When I try to gdb it , I get the following errors.
Is it a libefence issue or what is it? I am unable to move further. Remember, my application is a C/C++, Javascript amalgamation.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x779288c4 in memalign () from /usr/lib/libefence.so
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x779288c4 in memalign () from /usr/lib/libefence.so
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x710fefe8 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
warning: GDB can't find the start of the function at 0x710fefe6.
```

Comment: do you have the debuginfo for ibefence.so? that will get you to the LINE where the segv happened.